# Extract a numeric value from a varchar column to compare with a numeric column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

How can I compare the value of amount given in two columns as shown in the attached picture? 'T', 'M' and 'B' in column 1 represent trillion, million and billion respectively. I have tried below mentioned code so far but that's not what I need.

```
left(f.name, CHARINDEX('M',f.name))
```

[image: See the attached image]

**NOTE:** The currency prefix could be: `$, GBP, GB, CAD` etc:

Comment: is the first space always right before the multiplier?  Use the index of the space and a `right(Substring,1)` to pull off the multipler, a `convert(decimal),left(substring, len(substring)-1)` for the value to multiply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string manipulation to extract the numeric portion of the string and the use `CASE` statements to multiply the values to produce a numeric value that can be used to compare the results.

**Sample query to perform conversion:**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (col1 VARCHAR(20), col2 DECIMAL (18, 2))

INSERT INTO #temp
        ( col1, col2 )
VALUES ('$55T Sales blah', 55000000000000),
       ('$30M Sales blah', 30000000),
       ('$0.3M Sales blah', 300000),
       ('$0.5B Sales blah', 500000000)

SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(col1, (CHARINDEX(' Sales', col1) - 1), 1) 
            WHEN 'T' 
            THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), SUBSTRING(col1, 2, (CHARINDEX(' Sales', col1) - 3))) * 1000000000000
            WHEN 'B' 
            THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), SUBSTRING(col1, 2, (CHARINDEX(' Sales', col1) - 3))) * 1000000000
            WHEN 'M' 
            THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), SUBSTRING(col1, 2, (CHARINDEX(' Sales', col1) - 3))) * 1000000
        END AS NumericValue, 
        col2
FROM #temp
```

From this data, you can simply compare the 2 columns, so you can wrap it in a subquery like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (col1 VARCHAR(20), col2 DECIMAL (18, 2))

INSERT INTO #temp
        ( col1, col2 )
VALUES ('$55T Sales blah', 55000000000000),
       ('$30M Sales blah', 30000000),
       ('$0.3M Sales blah', 300000),
       ('$0.5B Sales blah', 500000000)

SELECT t.NumericValue, 
       t.col2, 
       CASE WHEN t.NumericValue = t.col2 
            THEN 'Match' 
            ELSE 'No Match' 
        END AS Match 
FROM ( SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(col1, (CHARINDEX(' Sales', col1) - 1), 1) 
                    WHEN 'T' 
                    THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), SUBSTRING(col1, 2, (CHARINDEX(' Sales', col1) - 3))) * 1000000000000
                    WHEN 'B' 
                    THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), SUBSTRING(col1, 2, (CHARINDEX(' Sales', col1) - 3))) * 1000000000
                    WHEN 'M' 
                    THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), SUBSTRING(col1, 2, (CHARINDEX(' Sales', col1) - 3))) * 1000000
                END AS NumericValue, 
                col2
        FROM #temp) t

DROP TABLE #temp
```

This assumes that the numeric portion is always followed by " Sales" and follows the formatting you have shown in your sample data. You can replace the " Sales" in `CHARINDEX` with a space if required.

**Output:**

```
NumericValue        col2                Match
==============================================
55000000000000.00   55000000000000.00   Match
30000000.00         30000000.00         Match
300000.00           300000.00           Match
500000000.00        500000000.00        Match
```

**Updated query to account for different prefixes:**

This uses `PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', col1)` to find the position of the first numeric value.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
      col1 VARCHAR(20) ,
      col2 DECIMAL(18, 2)
    )

INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( col1, col2 )
VALUES  ( 'GBP55T Sales blah', 55000000000000 ),
        ( '$30M Sales blah', 30000000 ),
        ( 'GB0.3M Sales blah', 300000 ),
        ( '$0.5B Sales blah', 500000000 )

SELECT  t.NumericValue ,
        t.col2 ,
        CASE WHEN t.NumericValue = t.col2 THEN 'Match'
             ELSE 'No Match'
        END AS Match
FROM    ( SELECT    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), SUBSTRING(col1,
                                                      PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', col1),
                                                      CHARINDEX(' ', col1)
                                                      - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',
                                                              col1) - 1))
                    * CASE SUBSTRING(col1, ( CHARINDEX(' ', col1) - 1 ), 1)
                        WHEN 'T' THEN 1000000000000
                        WHEN 'B' THEN 1000000000
                        WHEN 'M' THEN 1000000
                      END AS NumericValue ,
                    col2
          FROM      #temp
        ) t

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Credit to [@Giorgi Nakeuri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29143192/57475) for the less verbose `CASE` statement.

Comment: Tanner, Thanks for explaining this in so much details. It works almost fine but there is just one bug left. Currency symbol for all the rows is not "$'. In some cases it could be CAD, GBP , GB etc. This is working well if we want the sub-string to start reading from point 2 in each case but that is not the situation. How can we improve it to start reading from the first numeric value?

Comment: @Tayyab that would have been useful information up front. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @ Tanner,, Thanks you so much ..  really appreciate the quick help

Answer (score 0):

This will demonstrate my comment above. It uses a combination of `LEFT(), RIGHT(), CHARINDEX() and SUBSTRING()` as well as a `CASE` to determine the multiplier value.

```
declare @Text varchar(20) = '$30M Sales in Jan 2014'


SELECT @Text [OriginalText]
    --select only the letter
    ,Right(left(@Text, CHARINDEX(' ',@Text)-1),1) [Multiplier]
    --this trims the multiplier and the dollar sign
    ,SUBSTRING(left(@Text, CHARINDEX(' ',@Text)-1),2, len(left(@Text, CHARINDEX(' ',@Text)-1))-2) [ValueToMultiply]
    ,CASE Right(left(@Text, CHARINDEX(' ',@Text)-1),1)
        WHEN 'T' then 1000000000000
        WHEN 'B' then 1000000000
        WHEN 'M' then 1000000
    END 
    *  Convert(decimal(18,4),SUBSTRING(left(@Text, CHARINDEX(' ',@Text)-1),2, len(left(@Text, CHARINDEX(' ',@Text)-1))-2)) [FinalValue]
```

This results in:

```
OriginalText          | Multiplier  | ValueToMultiply   | FinalValue
$30M Sales in Jan 20  | M           | 30                | 30000000.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( A NVARCHAR(MAX) )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '$55T sdlkjf' ),
        ( '$30M sdlkjf' ),
        ( '$0.30M sdlkjf' ),
        ( '$0.5B sdlkjf' )


SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING(A, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', A) - 2) AS MONEY)
        * CASE SUBSTRING(A, CHARINDEX(' ', A) - 1, 1)
            WHEN 'T' THEN 1000000000000
            WHEN 'B' THEN 1000000000
            WHEN 'M' THEN 1000000
            ELSE 1
          END AS Result
FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
Result
55000000000000.0000
30000000.0000
300000.0000
500000000.0000
```

Answer (score -1):

TRY
[SUBSTRING()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), [REPLACE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

CAN USE:

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

e.g:

```
declare @val as varchar(200)='T31M4B5'

select 
CAST(
  (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Val,'M',''),'B',''),'T',''))
as int) as val
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f05a09/2)